# AWS API Gateway: When to create another API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

This conceptual question has crept into my mind after becoming more familiar with AWS.  In general, I’m curious if there is a best-practice and/or convention as to when an API provider should group endpoints into a new, separate API (vs. lumping the endpoints into an existing API).

To illustrate, let’s say a **Service** creates digital wallet coupons on behalf of `Manufacturers`, to be redeemed by `Consumers` at a bunch of `Mom & pop stores` — some of the activities the **Service** might engage in include:

- Receiving data from the `Manufacturers` (in order to build the digital coupons)
- Providing a mechanism for `Consumers` to find and download coupons
- Providing a way for the `Mom & pop stores’` payment terminals to validate the coupons

And, oh by the way, the **Service** might also be required to ...

- Implement a variety of endpoints, based on technologies involved (e.g., [PassKit with Apple Wallet](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PassKit_WebService/WebService.html))

**So?**

With AWS, it’s easy to modularize one’s backend (e.g., have an RDS instance for the database, run a few lambda functions for microservices, etc.) and load balance it all.  API Gateway adds to this in that each endpoint can point to different things (lambda functions, EC2 instances via HTTP proxy, etc.).

Consequently, one approach might be to define ***one*** API in AWS API Gateway and have all the endpoints underneath it:

```
API: “Master”
  /coupon
    POST = create a new one (for Manufacturers)
    PUT = update an existing one (for Manufacturers)
    GET = retrieve one (for Consumers)

  /coupon/validate
    POST = verify it’s still valid (Mom & Pop store use-case)

  /apple-wallet
     /{version}
         /passes
             ... per documentation
         /devices
             ... per documentation
```

But would it make more sense for the **Service** to shave off the `/apple-wallet` endpoint and create an entirely new, separate API?

Alternatively, if the **Service** was going to publish documentation for public developers to use, would it make sense to move the `Manufacturer`-relevant endpoints into a separate API altogether?

Since AWS makes the effort of splitting endpoints so simple via API Gateway, are there any standard practices for when you should (or should not)?

Thank you for any insights / opinions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My two cents. **Think about your end-user** for your APIs. You will have **different developer end-users** for each API set.

Your ideal situation will have **each developer end-user only seeing the APIs that are relevant to them**. So you should split your APIs into different Gateways according to the end-users

In the theoretical situation you describe:

- Create an **API for Manufacturers** so they can integrate with you to create coupons. If you do the integration internally it will be the corporate sales and presales people who talk to the manufacturers
- The users for the Service and End User coupons might end up being the
  same app developers that create an interface for both stores and
  users. So create a **coupon API** for them

Separating both should also give you security benefits as you will protect the knowledge of your Manufacturer API from the users who might try to hack it